# Run a windows service with uiaccess flag

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8

I have a program that I want to display a window above the start screen in Windows 8. The only way to do that (that I know of) requires I set the flag uiaccess=true in the manifest. But, in order for that to work, the user of the program needs to be an administrator. So, I tried [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18367/Launch-your-application-in-Vista-under-the-local-s) to get a service I install with the program to launch the main program. This way the any user can run the program once installed.

The problem is the uiaccess flag. It seems that in order to launch a program as described in the article, but with uiaccess, the service itself needs to have the uiaccess flag enabled (or else CreateProcessAsUser fails). And whenever I try to install the service with the uiaccess flag, I get the error "this process requires elevation."

So, the main question is: Is there a way to install a service that has this flag enabled? I admit that I expect the answer to be "no". Since a service running in session 0 would normally have no reason to have this flag, since there's no ui component allowed. But, I'm hoping that I'm wrong and there is a way.

Thank you, let me know if I need to clear up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before CreateProcessAsUser and after DuplicateHandle use function SetTokenInformation with TokenUIAccess 1

Comment: Thanks! That solved that problem perfectly(unfortunately there's still issues with what I'm trying to do, but that's another topic).